# Getting 3rd party car insurance for Iran from Pakistan

Tags: overland, road-trips, iran, pakistan, carnet-de-passage

We are Australians driving our New South Wales (state in Australia) registered vehicle from Sydney to the United Kingdom.  Currently in Sri Lanka, we head next back to India, Pakistan then Iran and so on.

*The question is* where in Pakistan can we get 3rd party car insurance? We have been told buying on the border is very expensive. All the info we find is re: people doing it "the other way" ie) coming from Europe so the place given to buy it (Maku) doesn't work as we'd be at the end of the trip! Presumably they let you in without insurance if you can say you're on your way to get it.

Does anyone know if we can get it in Zahedan? Or where else in this area or in Pakistan before crossing?

Answer (score 6):

Lahore isn't far at all from the border and is a *huge* city, so if anywhere allows you to buy insurance, Lahore will. I can't seem to find any info on it immediately, but you could try talking to the chaps at [The Regale Internet Inn](http://wikitravel.org/en/Lahore#Budget_2) who are just the nicest people you could possibly meet, they may well have the appropriate contacts.

I can only imagine the amount of hassle you would have getting insurance in Zahddan. It took me 8 hours to DRIVE THROUGH IT due to the escorts and bureaucracy, let alone go into the centre and try and find somebody to stamp some paperwork.

Personally when I went through those countries I didn't get any insurance at all. Their worth is fairly spurious and chasing up the companies that supposedly back the documents would be tremendously difficult in a tight spot.

As always with questions like this I would recommend you check out  [Horizons Unlimited](http://www.horizonsunlimited.com)
as they tend to be the best place to get up to date info on this sort of thing (I went thorough Iran and Pakistan in 2009).

Answer (score 5):

Insurance is not common in Pakistan. Even if you got insurance it take a lot time for claims if you need it. [EFU](http://www.efuinsurance.com/product_services/motor.php) is one of the big companies that provided insurance in Pakistan

Answer (score 1):

Your only requirement is the *Carnet de Passage*. This is sometimes confused with the triptych (but they are not the same thing).

You would have had one already since you are already on your trip. Motor vehicle insurance is not mandatory in Pakistan.